# Equilateral triangle and vectors

Tags: vectors

We have an equilateral triangle $ABC$ and it's height $AD$. Point $S$ lies on the line $AD$. How to express $\vec{BS}$ by $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{BC}$. I think it's neccesery here to add a parameter but so far I haven't find it.

Comment: I'm not sure if my result is ok but I obtain $\vec{BS}=\vec{AB}+m(\vec{AB}-\frac{1}{2}\vec{BC})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the fact that:
$$
\vec{AB} + \vec{BC} + \vec{CA} = 0
$$
to get:
$$
\vec{AC} = \vec{AB} + \vec{BC}
$$
Any point $S$ on the height is parametrized as:
$$
\vec{AS} = \vec{AB} + \vec{BS} = \alpha\left(\frac{\vec{AB} + \vec{AC}}{2}\right)
$$
where $\alpha \in[0,1]$. Thus, 
$$
\vec{BS} = \alpha\left(\frac{2\vec{AB} + \vec{BC} }{2}\right) - \vec{AB} \\
= \boxed{(\alpha - 1) \vec{AB} + \frac{\alpha}{2}\vec{BC}}
$$
You can confirm that at the extreme values of $\alpha$, $S$ coincides with $A$ or with $D$.